# Managing AWS Parameter Store variables with a data migrations tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-parameter-store

We are increasingly using AWS Parameter Store for managing configuration.

One issue we have is managing which variables need to be set when releases occur to different environments (staging, dev, prod etc). There is always a lot of work to configure the different environments, and it is easy to overlook required settings when we release microservices.

It seems what is needed is a database migration similar to Flyway or Liquibase, but I haven't found any products available, and it is unclear to me how secrets would be managed with this system.

What are people doing to manage pushing new configuration into Parameter Store when new application code is deployed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know [AWS AppConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/what-is-appconfig.html)? It’s a different way of managing configuration and I’m not sure if this fits your requirements but it might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, good to know about AppConfig but I don't think it fits our issue. AppConfig is more about deploying configuration on to instances, but the question still remains, how do you create the configuration in the first place.